# Can SharePoint perform full-text indexing on SSRS reports?

Tags: search, reporting-services, crawling

We have installed SSRS on SP2013 on-premise. The report files (*.rdl) can be opened by users but the content are not being indexed. May I know is it possible to setup indexing on SSRS content?

P.S. We can search out the SSRS reports by title or filename but not the content.

Comment: I'm no expert, but perhaps an older hand at SSRS. I thought through your question, and came back with not being able to index content because until the .rdl file is called, the content is not there, just the query to find the content. I then thought that maybe if you set the report up to take snapshots of the data that you could at least index the snapshot of the content. I did not, however find any information regarding indexing the content of report snapshots, so if there is a way, it's either not documented or not easily found.

Comment: I open the .rdl file with notepad and find some metadata. e.g. Title of report. Do you think they can be indexed?

Comment: Based on what I have previously researched, you should be able to index the title to the report using the MetadataExtractorTitle property. I found this page to provide some insight as to how: [site](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/understand-sharepoint-crawled-and-managed-properties-for-search)